# After install a golang package, it doesn't work

Tags: go, package

I'm new on golang. According this [instructions](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata), to install `go-bindata`, I should use this command:

```
$ go get -u github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...
```

I did it. After that, I checked on `$GOPATH/src/jteeuwen/go-bindata/` and there's a file `go-bindata.a`. It seems like it was installed, but it doesn't work:

```
$ go-bindata
-bash: go-bindata: command not found
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I'm using OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add $GOPATH/bin to your $PATH.

Comment: Thank you. I just found it.