# Go package unusable after installation

Tags: go, package

I recently installed a new package for one of my Go introductory projects named [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata#installation), I have followed the installation guide, but after I tried to run the command, this showed up.

```sh
$ go-bindata
bash: go-bindata: command not found
```

I have referred to one similar problem on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406195/after-install-a-golang-package-it-doesnt-work), and the solution given is setting `$GOPATH`, I'm on a windows operating system, and I have already configured my `$GOPATH` in `$PATH` as the image shown below, I don't know which step I got wrong.

[Environment vairiable & Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk4SA.png)

(I'm sorry for the inconvience on the attached image since I'm not allowed to attach an image directly to the post.)

Comment: Can you tell us the steps you did to install the package, e.g. `go install ...` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To perform the installation with modern versions of Go, you should run:

```
go install github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/go-bindata@latest
```

This command will compile and put the binary into the `GOPATH\bin` folder on your machine, so if you want to be able to run it from anywhere, you should add `GOPATH\bin` to your `PATH`.

And then try and run it:

```
go-bindata
```

It's a bit awkward repetition, because of the project directory structure. The first `go-bindata` is github username, the second is the project name and the third is where the main package of the program is to be found.

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked, I'll add this to my own GitHub issue repo for reviewing later on, and I'll cite your source.